# Tikz Overlay with shift={(label)} produces the overlay on the next page

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, overlays

I apologize in advance for the rather large MWE, but it was the only way to reproduce the issue. In the current form the overlay that should go over the `alignat*` environment after the commented `\newpage` appears on the second page of the document.

Removing the space before the line `\vspace{42pt}Thus,` creates unwanted spacing for said line by shifting it up. It also does not solve the overlay positioning.

Why does the overlay appear on the next page? It seems to have taken the correct `shift` position, just on the wrong page.

I don't know if it is worth noting, but the preamble of my actual tex document is much larger. I'm not sure if it is relevant to reproduce, but I can if it is deemed necessary or requested.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{actuarialangle,tikz,tikz-cd}

\usepackage[top=40pt,bottom=50pt,left=35pt,right=35pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-8pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{+10pt}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.55}[1.0]{$-$}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\subsection{\underline{Exercise 2.}}
\textit{A widow, as beneficiary of a $\$100\,000$ insurance policy, will receive $\$20\,000$ immediately and $\$1800$ every three months thereafter. The company pays interest at $j_4=6\%$; after 3 years, the rate is increased to $j_4=7\%$. $a)$ How many full payments of $\$1800$ will she receive? $b)$ What additional sum paid with the last full payment will exhaust her benefits? $c)$ What payment 3 months after the last full payment will exhaust her benefits?}
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\node [above] at (0.5,0.2) {\$100,000};
\node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{10pt}] at (-1.5,0) {Cash\\scenario:};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
\draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
\draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
\draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
\draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
\draw (12.1,0) -- (14,0);
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
\draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
\draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
\draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
\draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
\draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
\node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
\node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
\node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
\node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
\node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
\draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
\draw [<-] (8.05,-1.2) to (15,-1.2);
\node [below] at (14.6,-0.2) {12+$[n]$ (quarters)};
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{10pt}] at (-2,0) {Annuity\\scenario:};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (4,-1.2) {$j_4=6\%$};
\node at (3.8,-1.7) {$\Rightarrow i=1.5\%$};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (11,-1.2) {$j_4=7\%$};
\node at (11.2,-1.7) {$i=1.75\%$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
\draw [fill=white] (0,0.5) ellipse (35pt and 7.5pt);
\node [inner sep=0pt,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{7pt},fill=white,align=center] at (0,0.5) {\$20,000};
\node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity};
\node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
After 3 years, the widow has received, in addition to the down payment, 12 full payments of \$1800, for a total present value of 
$$\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}\cong\$39,633.51<\$100,000$$
Thus, the (wo)man will still receive some payments afterwards. But how many?\\
The ``theoretical'' number of payments to be received after 3 years must satisfy the equation \\
\begin{align*}
    \text{PV of cash scenario }&=\text{ PV of annuity scenario}\\
    \$100,000\quad&=\quad\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt]\node[] (x) {};\$39,633.51\quad+\quad\$1800a_{\angl n1.75\%} \,\,\cdot\,\,(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(x)}]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,mirror}] (0,-0.2) to (2,-0.2);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,mirror}] (3.2,-0.2) to (5.7,-0.2);
\tikzstyle{every node}=[align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}]
\node at (1.1,-1.2) {\footnotesize{PV of first}\\\footnotesize{3 years of}\\\footnotesize{annuity +}\\\footnotesize{\$20,000 down}};
\node at (4.6,-1.2) {\footnotesize{PV of remainder}\\\footnotesize{of annuity, i.e.}\\\footnotesize{value of remainder}\\\footnotesize{at time $n=12$}};
\node at (7.8,-1) {\footnotesize{discount factor}\\\footnotesize{from time $n=12$}\\\footnotesize{to $n=0$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\newpage %%%%%%%% WEIRD STUFF HAPPENS IF I DO NOT ADD THIS PAGE BREAK

\vspace{42pt}Thus,
\begin{spreadlines}{\dimexpr\jot+0.75em\relax}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&\quad \$100,000-\$39,633.51&=\frac{\$1800a_{\angl n1.75\%}}{(1.015)^{12}}\\
\iff&& \frac{\$60,366.49(1.015)^{12}}{\$1800}&=\frac{1-(1.0175)^{\minus n}}{0.0175}\\
\iff&&\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}&=1-\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt]\node[] (n101) {};(1.0175)^{\minus n}\\
\iff &&(1.0175)^{\minus n}&=1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}\\
\iff && -n\ln 1.0175&=\ln\left[1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800} \right]\\
\iff && n&=\frac{\ln\left[1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}\right]}{-\ln1.0175}\\
&& &\cong69.73
\end{alignat*}
\end{spreadlines}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(n101)}]
\draw [->] (0,-0.2) to[out=210,in=330,looseness=0.5] (-2,-0.2);
\draw [->] (-3,-0.4) to[out=330,in=210,looseness=0.5] (-0.25,-0.5);
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{9pt}] at (-6.4,-3.3) {\small{taking}\\\small{$\ln$ of}\\\small{both sides}};
\end{tikzpicture}
So the widow will receive 69 full payments after the first 3 years of payments, i.e. (s)he will receive a total of $69+12=81$ full payments of $\$1800$.
\vspace{12pt}(b)\vspace{-12pt}
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
\draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
\draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
\draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
\draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
\draw (12.1,0) -- (14,0);
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
\draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
\draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
\draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
\draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
\draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
\draw (14,-1) -- (14,-1.4);
\node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (14.45,0.2) {$\$1800+X$};
\node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
\node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
\node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
\node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
\node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
\draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
\draw [<->] (8.05,-1.2) to (13.95,-1.2);
\node [below] at (14.95,-0.2) {81 (quarters)};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (4,-1.2) {$i=1.5\%$};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (11,-1.2) {$i=1.75\%$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
\node at (0,1.3) {\$20,000};
\node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 1};
\node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 2};
\draw [->] (15.25,1.4) to (15.25,0.8);
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{9pt}] at (15.25,1.8) {\footnotesize{balloon}\\\footnotesize{payment}};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
The balloon payment $X$ must be such that
\begin{spreadlines}{\dimexpr\jot+0.75em\relax}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&& \text{PV of cash scenario}&=\text{PV of annuity scenario}\\
&&\$100,000&=\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt]\node[] (n100) {};\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}+\$1800a_{\angl{69}1.75\%}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
&& &\quad\quad+X(1+1.75\%)^{\minus69}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus18}\\
&& &=\$20,000+\$19,633.51+\$60,040.76+0.2526577697X\\
\iff&& \$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76&=0.2526577697X\\
\iff&& X&=\frac{\$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76}{0.2526577697X}\\
&& &\cong\$1,289.21
\end{alignat*}
\end{spreadlines}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(n100)}]
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{7pt}] at (1,-0.35) {\scriptsize{down}\\\scriptsize{payment}};
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{7pt}] at (3,-0.35) {\scriptsize{PV of annuity 1}};
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{7pt}] at (5.7,-0.45) {\scriptsize{PV of annuity 2}};
\node [align=left,execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{7pt}] at (8,-0.5) {\scriptsize{discount}\\\scriptsize{factor}};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror}] (4.7,-0.15) to (7.1,-0.15);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror}] (7.2,-0.15) to (9.1,-0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
Thus, the additional sum paid with the last full payment, called balloon payment, to exhaust the widows's benefits is \$1,289.21.
\vspace{12pt}(c)
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
\draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
\draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
\draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
\draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
\draw (12.1,0) -- (16,0);
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
\draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
\draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
\draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
\draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
\draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
\draw (16,0.2) -- (16,-0.2);
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
\draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
\draw (16,-1) -- (16,-1.4);
\node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (14,0.2) {\$1800};
\node [above] at (16,0.2) {$Y$};
\node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
\node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
\node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
\node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
\node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
\node [below] at (14,-0.2) {81};
\draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
\draw [<->] (8.05,-1.2) to (15.95,-1.2);
\node [below] at (16.95,-0.2) {82 (quarters)};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (4,-1.2) {$i=1.5\%$};
\node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (12,-1.2) {$i=1.75\%$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
\node at (0,1.3) {\$20,000};
\node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 1};
\node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
The drop payment $Y$ is such that 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&& \text{PV of cash scenario}&=\text{PV of annuity scenario}\\
&&\$100,000&=\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}+\$1800a_{\angl{69}1.75\%}(1_1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
&& &\quad\quad+Y(1+1.75\%)^{\minus70}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
&& &=\$20,000+\$19,633.51+\$60,040.76+0.2483123044Y\\
%&& &\quad\quad+0.
\iff&& Y&=\frac{\$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76}{0.2483123044}\\
&& &\cong\$1311.78
\end{alignat*}
Hence, the payment 3 months after the last full payment, also called drop payment, which will exhaust the widow's benefits is \$1311.78.
%\vspace{8em}\hyperref[toc]{\textit{\underline{\footnotesize{Return to the Table of Contents}}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in your large document, is every `tikzpicture` entered the same way, between `\begingroup ... \endgroup` with the explicit `\addtolength{\jot}{...}` repeated, or is the document less "segmented"?  have you tried separately processing the first half of the document, then the second half?  do both halves fail, or can you isolate smaller portions that don't fail?

Comment: This was my first attempt at using `\addtolength...`. Had it worked as intended I probably would make some changes in order to utilize it elsewhere.
In the large document nothing fails, it just produces the `\alignat*` environment without the overlay.

Comment: Unlike \addtocounter, \addtolength is not global.  \global\advance\jot by 0.75em might be what you are looking for.

Comment: If you load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`, you can say `\begin{spreadlines}{\dimexpr\jot+0.75em\relax} \begin{alignat*}{2} ... \end{alignat*} \end{spreadlines}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried replacing `\jot` with `\global\advance\jot` and got an error for that line: You can't use `global' after \advance

Comment: @TorbjørnT. your result produced the correct spacing but, as with using `\addtolength...`, the overlay does not appear.

Comment: \advance replaces \addtolength (or more precisely, \addtolength is implemented using \advance).  Try adding `\global\jot=\jot` after.

Comment: @JohnKormylo As with Torbjørn's result, the space is added correctly, but the overlay does not appear :(

Comment: Worked fine here. Did you compile twice? Do you have any other `node`s called `p` in a `remember picture` context?

Comment: I did compile twice and I have no other nodes named `p`.

As with my MWE above, it works there, it's in the 2400+ line document I'm compiling that it doesn't work.

Comment: I just noticed now that the overlay arrows do appear, but on the next page which is empty except for one line at the top of the page. They appear to be in the correct position, but on the next page. Removing the lines that instigate the next page has no effect, the page is still created and has only the overlay arrows on it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In the subsequent `alignat` environment I again place a remember picture node and a following overlay that works perfectly using the `spreadlines` environment. For some reason it is just the case that produces the arrows on the next page. Very strange.

Comment: Don't leave a blank line or any space before the overlay. If necessary, put that code first.

Comment: @cfr What do you mean put the code first? 

I've made sure there are no spaces but it doesn't change anything. Overlay still appears on the next page.

Comment: Put the overlay code before the stuff it is overlaying. You can use `tikzmark` if you get errors that way.

Comment: @cfr i've never used tikzmark before. Can you provide an example for this case?

Comment: You need to provide an example which **demonstrates the problem**. Your code produces a single page and everything is as it should be. If we can't reproduce the issue, how can we help? There's no point in my spending time on an arbitrary example with `tikzmark`: you can see the manual for that. If you gave me code which reproduced the problem, that would be different. As it is, there is nothing to do.

Comment: @cfr That's a very good point! I'm new here and still learning but ya that seems about as reasonable as you can get! I'll edit the question and include the problem, I was able to reproduce it, though it's a much bigger MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `tikzmark`. With `tikzmark` you can specify the overlay *before* the mark is defined in the text, so that you can simply move overlay pictures *before* the text they belong with when necessary.

I've also eliminated most of the bad boxes (1 left) and cleaned up a little.

- Don't use `$$` for display maths in LaTeX.
- Don't use `\\` to end lines outside special environments, such as `tabular` and `array`.
- Don't put `tikzpicture`s in maths mode! (No idea at all why anybody *would* do this, but you *did*, so presumably there's some motivation. Whatever the reason, it is not a good one.)
- Font size commands (among others) such as `\Huge`, `\small`, `\footnotesize` etc. **do not take arguments**. `\small{abc} def` is just like `\small abc def`. In both cases `abc def` will be typeset in a smaller font than the default.
- Do use Ti*k*Z's styles and make custom styles to simplify your code.

In the code below, I've used colours to make the overlays more visible. Obviously, this should be removed for production use.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{actuarialangle,tikz,tikz-cd}

\usepackage[top=40pt,bottom=50pt,left=35pt,right=35pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-8pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{+10pt}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.55}[1.0]{$-$}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}
\tikzset{%
  node font size/.style n args=2{%
    align=left, font=#1, execute at begin node=\setlength\baselineskip{#2}%
  },
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\subsection{\underline{Exercise 2.}}
\textit{A widow, as beneficiary of a $\$100\,000$ insurance policy, will receive $\$20\,000$ immediately and $\$1800$ every three months thereafter. The company pays interest at $j_4=6\%$; after 3 years, the rate is increased to $j_4=7\%$. $a)$ How many full payments of $\$1800$ will she receive? $b)$ What additional sum paid with the last full payment will exhaust her benefits? $c)$ What payment 3 months after the last full payment will exhaust her benefits?}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
    \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
    \node [above] at (0.5,0.2) {\$100,000};
    \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
    \node [node font size={\normalsize}{10pt}] at (-1.5,0) {Cash\\scenario:};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
      \draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
      \draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
      \draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
      \draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
      \draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
      \draw (12.1,0) -- (14,0);
      \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
      \draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
      \draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
      \draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
      \draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
      \draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
      \draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
      \draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
      \node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
      \node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
      \node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
      \node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
      \node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
      \draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
      \draw [<-] (8.05,-1.2) to (15,-1.2);
      \node [below] at (14.6,-0.2) {12+$[n]$ (quarters)};
      \node [node font size={\normalsize}{10pt}] at (-2,0) {Annuity\\scenario:};
      \node [fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (4,-1.2) {$j_4=6\%$};
      \node at (3.8,-1.7) {$\Rightarrow i=1.5\%$};
      \node [fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (11,-1.2) {$j_4=7\%$};
      \node at (11.2,-1.7) {$i=1.75\%$};
      \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
      \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
      \draw [fill=white] (0,0.5) ellipse (35pt and 7.5pt);
      \node [inner sep=0pt,node font size={\normalsize}{7pt},fill=white,align=center] at (0,0.5) {\$20,000};
      \node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity};
      \node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\end{center}

After 3 years, the widow has received, in addition to the down payment, 12 full payments of \$1800, for a total present value of
\[\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}\cong\$39,633.51<\$100,000\]
Thus, the (wo)man will still receive some payments afterwards. But how many?\\
The ``theoretical'' number of payments to be received after 3 years must satisfy the equation \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={({pic cs:x})}, red]
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,mirror}] (0,-0.2) to (2,-0.2);
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,mirror}] (3.2,-0.2) to (5.7,-0.2);
  \tikzset{node font size={\footnotesize}{8pt}}
  \node at (1.1,-1.2) {{PV of first}\\{3 years of}\\{annuity +}\\{\$20,000 down}};
\node at (4.6,-1.2) {{PV of remainder}\\{of annuity, i.e.}\\{value of remainder}\\{at time $n=12$}};
\node  at (7.8,-1) {discount factor\\from time $n=12$\\to $n=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{align*}
  \text{PV of cash scenario }&=\text{ PV of annuity scenario}\\
  \$100,000\quad&=\quad\tikzmark{x}\$39,633.51\quad+\quad\$1800a_{\angl n1.75\%} \,\,\cdot\,\,(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}
\end{align*}

\vspace{42pt}%
Thus,
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={({pic cs:n101})},blue]
  \draw [->] (0,-0.2) to[out=210,in=330,looseness=0.5] (-2,-0.2);
  \draw [->] (-3,-0.4) to[out=330,in=210,looseness=0.5] (-0.25,-0.5);
  \node [node font size={\small}{9pt}] at (-6.4,-3.3) {taking\\$\ln$ of\\both sides};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{spreadlines}{\dimexpr\jot+0.75em\relax}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    &&\quad \$100,000-\$39,633.51&=\frac{\$1800a_{\angl n1.75\%}}{(1.015)^{12}}\\
    \iff&& \frac{\$60,366.49(1.015)^{12}}{\$1800}&=\frac{1-(1.0175)^{\minus n}}{0.0175}\\
    \iff&&\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}&=1-\tikzmark{n101}(1.0175)^{\minus n}\\
    \iff &&(1.0175)^{\minus n}&=1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}\\
    \iff && -n\ln 1.0175&=\ln\left[1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800} \right]\\
    \iff && n&=\frac{\ln\left[1-\frac{60,366.49(1.015)^{12}(0.0175)}{1800}\right]}{-\ln1.0175}\\
    && &\cong69.73
  \end{alignat*}
\end{spreadlines}
So the widow will receive 69 full payments after the first 3 years of payments, i.e. (s)he will receive a total of $69+12=81$ full payments of $\$1800$.
\vspace{12pt}(b)\vspace{-12pt}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
    \draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
    \draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
    \draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
    \draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
    \draw (12.1,0) -- (14,0);
    \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
    \draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
    \draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
    \draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
    \draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
    \draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
    \draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
    \draw (14,-1) -- (14,-1.4);
    \node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
    \node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
    \node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
    \node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
    \node [above] at (14.45,0.2) {$\$1800+X$};
    \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
    \node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
    \node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
    \node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
    \node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
    \draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
    \draw [<->] (8.05,-1.2) to (13.95,-1.2);
    \node [below] at (14.95,-0.2) {81 (quarters)};
    \node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (4,-1.2) {$i=1.5\%$};
    \node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (11,-1.2) {$i=1.75\%$};
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
    \node at (0,1.3) {\$20,000};
    \node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 1};
    \node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 2};
    \draw [->] (15.25,1.4) to (15.25,0.8);
    \node [node font size={\footnotesize}{9pt}] at (15.25,1.8) {balloon\\payment};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The balloon payment $X$ must be such that
\begin{spreadlines}{\dimexpr\jot+0.75em\relax}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    && \text{PV of cash scenario}&=\text{PV of annuity scenario}\\
    &&\$100,000&=\tikzmark{n100}\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}+\$1800a_{\angl{69}1.75\%}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
    && &\quad\quad+X(1+1.75\%)^{\minus69}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus18}\\
    && &=\$20,000+\$19,633.51+\$60,040.76+0.2526577697X\\
    \llap{$\iff$}&& \$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76&=0.2526577697X\\
    \llap{$\iff$}&& X&=\frac{\$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76}{0.2526577697X}\\
    && &\cong\$1,289.21
  \end{alignat*}
\end{spreadlines}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={({pic cs:n100})}, node font size={\normalsize}{7pt}, green]
  \node [font=\scriptsize] at (1,-0.35) {down\\payment};
  \node  at (3,-0.35) {{PV of annuity 1}};
  \node  at (5.7,-0.45) {{PV of annuity 2}};
  \node  at (8,-0.5) {{discount}\\{factor}};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror}] (4.7,-0.15) to (7.1,-0.15);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror}] (7.2,-0.15) to (9.1,-0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent Thus, the additional sum paid with the last full payment, called balloon payment, to exhaust the widows's benefits is \$1,289.21.
\vspace{12pt}(c)
\begin{center}
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
      \draw (6.1,0.2) -- (5.9,-0.2);
      \draw (6.2,0.2) -- (6,-0.2);
      \draw (6.1,0) -- (12,0);
      \draw (12.1,0.2) -- (11.9,-0.2);
      \draw (12.2,0.2) -- (12,-0.2);
      \draw (12.1,0) -- (16,0);
      \draw (0,0.2) -- (0,-0.2);
      \draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
      \draw (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
      \draw (8,0.2) -- (8,-0.2);
      \draw (10,0.2) -- (10,-0.2);
      \draw (14,0.2) -- (14,-0.2);
      \draw (16,0.2) -- (16,-0.2);
      \draw (0,-1) -- (0,-1.4);
      \draw (8,-1) -- (8,-1.4);
      \draw (16,-1) -- (16,-1.4);
      \node [above] at (2,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (4,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (8,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (10,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (14,0.2) {\$1800};
      \node [above] at (16,0.2) {$Y$};
      \node [below] at (0,-0.2) {0};
      \node [below] at (2,-0.2) {1};
      \node [below] at (4,-0.2) {2};
      \node [below] at (8,-0.2) {12};
      \node [below] at (10,-0.2) {13};
      \node [below] at (14,-0.2) {81};
      \draw [<->] (0.05,-1.2) to (7.95,-1.2);
      \draw [<->] (8.05,-1.2) to (15.95,-1.2);
      \node [below] at (16.95,-0.2) {82 (quarters)};
      \node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (4,-1.2) {$i=1.5\%$};
      \node [fill=white,inner sep=2pt] at (12,-1.2) {$i=1.75\%$};
      \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0.8) to (7.975,0.8);
      \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (8.025,0.8) to (14,0.8);
      \node at (0,1.3) {\$20,000};
      \node at (4.8,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 1};
      \node at (11.4,1.4) {simple ordinary annuity 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\end{center}
The drop payment $Y$ is such that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && \text{PV of cash scenario}&=\text{PV of annuity scenario}\\
  &&\$100,000&=\$20,000+\$1800a_{\angl{12}1.5\%}+\$1800a_{\angl{69}1.75\%}(1_1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
  && &\quad\quad+Y(1+1.75\%)^{\minus70}(1+1.5\%)^{\minus12}\\
  && &=\$20,000+\$19,633.51+\$60,040.76+0.2483123044Y\\
  %&& &\quad\quad+0.
  \iff&& Y&=\frac{\$100,000-\$20,000-\$19,633.51-\$60,040.76}{0.2483123044}\\
  && &\cong\$1311.78
\end{alignat*}
Hence, the payment 3 months after the last full payment, also called drop payment, which will exhaust the widow's benefits is \$1311.78.
\end{document}
```

[image: matching overlays without pain]

Comment: wow thank you. I'd like to apologize in advance for my inaccurate colloquial language usage in some questions, but, if I may...Is `node font size` a function you are defining or is it prebuilt and you're just setting it up to be used more efficiently for the given case? Is `$$. . .$$` the environment you're saying I shouldn't use? What is the difference between using `$$. . .$$` and `\[. . .\]`? I actually only learned recently that double line break in the .tex file produces a line break in the compiled version, is that the standard way to produce a line break, as opposed to using `\\`?

Comment: I'm defining `node font size`. There's a question somewhere about `$$ ... $$`. Basically, `\[...\]` gives better spacing in almost all cases. (There are some very unusual cases where it may be worse, but these are very rare.) The usual way to start a new paragraph is to leave a blank line. `\noindent` stops indentation. Environments such as `flushleft` are different and `\\ ` is fine to use there. (Though leaving a blank line would also work.) Generally, you'll get bad boxes with `\\ ` outside special environments, though I can't remember whether I did in every case here or not.

Comment: @Francesco What's wrong with your language? Seems fine to me.

Comment: thanks for the follow up clarifications!!! I wasn't sure if it was right or wrong, just politely covering my bases. I've heard the term macro and I'm not sure if that is the same thing as a function in latex or what specifically it is.

Comment: @Francesco Macros are anything like `\command` which isn't a primitive or otherwise special, I guess. Very roughly, that is. There aren't really any functions. LaTeX 3 has the concept of a function, but functions are still macros - the concept is just, really, implemented in a set of conventions for naming things.

Comment: @Francesco I don't know much about other languages, but I am guessing that what you'd call functions, variables, constants etc. are all macros in TeX. There's no distinction.

Comment: oh, see I didn't know that. Again, thanks for the clarification. I'm also curious to know why you used `\llap`, I looked up what this command does and while I read the description it doesn't appear to have done that here, perhaps because the line was so wide?

Comment: @Francesco I tried to put the `\iff` into the margin as that seemed better than having the stuff run into the margin on the other side.

Comment: `@cfr` I've been using your macro for setting the font size and lineskip  to much success. However sometimes I notice that when I modify the lineskip after the initial creation, it sometimes does nothing or that even though I set a value it doesn't create the lineskip of the desired pt. Can you explain this? Does this require a new thread?

Comment: @Francesco I think a new question with a link to this one and an example of the behaviour would be best. I'm afraid nothing obvious springs to mind, but only questions which would be more simply addressed by a new example.